# How to install Ubuntu OS on a Windows 7 OS PC and use both of them?

Tags: software-installation, windows-7

How can I install the Ubuntu OS on a PC running Windows 7?

Is it possible to use both Ubuntu and Windows 7 at the same time?

Can I return back to Windows 7 later on?

Comment: What have you done?

Answer (score -1):

Look into this. https://www.virtualbox.org/

You can also run Ubuntu alongside Windows in a dual boot. Ubuntu has an option for that when you install it from a disk or USB. Don't need to turn back to Windows 7 if you're not sure about it. Try the dual boot I suggested and see for yourself. I won't go into detail about it because it's swarming around google. "Dual booting Ubuntu and Windows." Look it up. :)